# ¿Cómo transformar información en json contenida en un URL a un Data Frame en Python?

Tags: python, json, base-de-datos, pandas, dataframe

Estoy buscando actualizar una base de datos. Los datos los tengo en un URL y están en `.json`, esa información la debo pasar a un DataFrame en Python.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

def igae_update():
  url = "https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/api/indicadores/desarrolladores/jsonxml/INDICATOR/496150/es/0700/false/BIE/2.0/15af1927-c511-41d4-0f03-4d328ff817f3?type=json"
  resp = requests.get(url).json()
  return pd.DataFrame(resp['Header'])

df = igae_update()
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutar la función, me aparece el siguiente error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Adjunto la imagen de la información de la base de datos en json que se debe transformar:

[image: Base de datos en json]

Muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que necesitas es la parte de los datos, sin tener en cuenta el header porque no podrás crear un dataframe.

Por otro lado, no subas fotografías porque no es nada legible. Yo no haría un json directamente de la respuesta. He pasado del str de la respuesta a un json, pero accediendo a los datos:

```
json.loads(response)["Series"][0]
```

Una vez ahí he pasado a un dataframe. Para que puedas recoger excepciones en un request, hazlo con un try except.

```
def igae_update():
    try:
        url = "https://www.inegi.org.mx/app/api/indicadores/desarrolladores/jsonxml/INDICATOR/496150/es/0700/false/BIE/2.0/15af1927-c511-41d4-0f03-4d328ff817f3?type=json"
        response = requests.get(url).text
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json.loads(response)["Series"][0])
        return data
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: 
        raise SystemExit(e)
```

Espero te sirva. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias, tu aportación ha sido de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Una buena forma de hacerlo, ya que estás usando Pandas, es usar directamente su función `pd.read_json()`, se puede ver en la [documentación oficial de pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)

Imaginemos que tenemos el siguiente archivo `.json`

```
{
    "col_1":[1,2,3,4,5],
    "col_2":[0,2,4,6,8],
    "col_3":[1,3,5,7,9]
}
```

Podríamos hacer el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_json("url/hacia_nuestro/archivo.json")
```

**Salida:**

```
  col_1 col_2 col_3
0   1     0     1
1   2     2     3
2   3     4     5
3   4     6     7
4   5     8     9
```